# Changing CSS style using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, width

I'm trying to modify the width of a div. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#foo')

[<div class=​"bar" id=​"foo" style=​"width:​ 40%">​</div>​]

$('#foo').css('style','width:50%')

[<div class=​"bar" id=​"foo" style=​"width:​ 40%">​</div>​]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$('#foo').css('width','50%')
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can follow either one of the following two methods.

```
$('#foo').css('width','50%')
```

Or

```
$('#foo').css({width:'50%'})
```

The second method is used to change multiple properties at one.