# How do I get JQuery to access my css style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I’m in my `_Layout.cshtml` page.  I’m trying to manipulate my menu bar using css and jquery.

Here’s what I’m trying to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var varElement = document.getElementsByTagName("var");
    for (var i = 0; i < varElement.length; i++) {
        varElement[i].style.fontSize = ".75";
    }
});
</script>
```

My problem is when I get to `varElement[i]`. I expected to see style in my intellisense but style is not in the list of properties.  The only items available in the intellisense list are:

```
Constructor
hasOwnProperty
isPrototypeOf
propertyIsEnumerable
toLocalString
toString
valueOf
```

How do I get JQuery to access my css style?

Comment: Most likely problem?...  The intellisense is imperfect.  Don't rely on it.  When you *run* the code, is there an error?  Unexpected behavior?  Visual Studio has gotten a *lot* better with JavaScript in recent versions (2012/2013), but it's not ideal just yet.

Comment: If you are just trying to change font size, please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236511/set-font-size-in-jquery#answer-3236532

Comment: And dont forget to add a unit to `.75`. Like `px`, `pt`, `%` ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing CSS style using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768142/changing-css-style-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

In `jQuery` you can set `CSS style` as below:

```
$('var').css('fontSize', .75)

$('body').css('background', '#f00');
```

Comment: isn't it `'font-size'`?

Comment: I think I just confirmed that the camelCase version *does* work. TIL

Comment: As long as you're adding examples, you should show the version where you can do `$('body').css({'background': '#f00', 'fontSize': .75});`

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the .css() method.  I'm not sure how you're using the for loop in your example, but on the jsfiddle is an example that includes a simple for loop, and hopefully that is helpful.

```
var changeStuff = function(){
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
$('#p'+i).css('font-size','3em');
```

}
};

http://jsfiddle.net/6UtyN/1/